# mx records aren't resolving on Amazon Route 53

Tags: email, postfix, gmail, amazon-route53

I've been trying to send mail to my new postfix configuration from my yahoo and gmail accounts and so far it has been nothing doing. On my Amazon Route 53 I have my mx record listed as:

`1 mail.example.com`

however, when I try to netcat:

`nc mail.example.com 25`

I get:

`getaddrinfo: Name or Service not known`

My domain was bought from NameCheap. Is there anything I have to do on that side? My website works flawlessly on Apache, but I don't even get errors in my mail log when sending with gmail and yahoo. I have ports `25` and `465` open on my EC2 server, but I do not have SSL or any kind of encryption scheme on my server.

Comment: So what's the domain? It's kinda hard to check for errors if we don't know it :)

Comment: Do you have an `A` record or a `CNAME` record for `mail.example.com`? If not, having an `MX` record that points to `mail.example.com` isn't going to help very much.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You're absolutely right. I did that and smooth sailing. Sven posted his answer a couple minutes before you did, but I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: I really wish that people would stop obfuscating their domain name when they ask questions like this. It makes it a guessing game as to what the problem is and makes it near impossible to provide insightful answers. If your domain name is a secret and divulging that information is some kind of security risk in your view then you shouldn't "publish" any services to the internet and having a borked MX record is a moot point.

Comment: @joeqwerty but yet two people were able to pinpoint exactly what my problem was rendering your argument a moot point. I don't know about you but I try to be as transparent as possible on the world wide web. The last thing I need is some rogue hacker poking around my server for an open relay, because he sees some newb system administrator who can barely set up an mx record.

Comment: @JohnBowlinger - You haven't mitigated any risk by obfuscating the information here. You've got a publicly available service and at the end of the day, it's not hidden from anyone. Obfuscating the information only makes it more difficult for us to provide insightful answers. Some of us will take the time to work out what's wrong and provide answers and some won't. I'm glad you got things sorted out but I don't see any benefit, real or perceived, to leaving the information out of your question.

Comment: joeqwerty, if a later question by the same asker shows a flaw in the network design, they'd look pretty silly showing people the front door in another question. Obfuscate away i say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to check:

- You'll need an `A` or `CNAME` record for `mail.example.com`, naturally. I don't know Route 53 and if they check this when you enter the data.
- DNS can take it's time to propagate everywhere (up to 24h in extreme cases).

Comment: Man, you beat me to it! That's exactly what I was missing. Set up a mail.example.com subdomain A record with that pointing to my server elastic ip address. After that, all good!